# I don't know where to start debugging my code

Tags: python

The project is to write a game that has a randomly generated number and you need to guess the number using various functions and return statements. Whenever you try this, this code asks for your guess, then doesnt return anything.

```
from random import randint 

TotalPoints = 0


def generateGuess():
    return(randint(1,10))

def CheckGuess(playerGuess, robotGuess, correct): 

    correct = False

    if playerGuess == robotGuess:
        global TotalPoints
        TotalPoints = TotalPoints + 5
        correct = True
        return correct
    else:
        correct = False
    return correct 


def retry ():    
    playagain = int(input("Do you want to play again? 1 for yes, 2 for no: "))

    if (playagain == 1):
        main()
    elif (playagain == 2):
        print("Game over! You ended with ", TotalPoints, "points!")
    else:
        print("error")


def main(): 
    print("Let's play the number Guessing Game! ")    

    playerGuess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
    robotGuess = generateGuess
    
    CheckGuess(playerGuess, robotGuess)


    if CheckGuess (correct = True):
        print("You guessed right! You have ", TotalPoints, "points!")
    elif CheckGuess (correct = False):
        print("You lost this round!")



main()
```

Comment: You need to call `generateGuess()` as a function (with the parenthesis). Otherwise you are just creating an alias to the function and not calling it. You should also be storing the result of `CheckGuess`, such as `result = CheckGuess(playerGuess, robotGuess)`. Then you can do `if result:` to see if the user guessed correctly.

Comment: And you call `CheckGuess` with single `correct` arguments while there are 3 required.

Comment: You could simplify your `CheckGuess` by removing the third argument. It is pointless.

Comment: When I run this code, I get an error, rather than it printing nothing.  Did you get the same error?  If so, the first step in debugging is to *read the error message* rather than treating it as "nothing" -- error messages are there to help you debug!

Comment: See the "Tricks for Trimming" section of http://sscce.org/ for guidance on narrowing your problem; to be on-topic here (or in most other forums), we expect some work to be done to build a [mre] -- the _shortest possible_ code that generates a well-defined problem when run without changes.

Comment: `robotGuess = generateGuess` You forgot the parentheses `()` after the function call...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title. If you want debugging tools, check out [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](/q/4929251/4518341) Most of them are a bit much for a newbie, but [I posted an answer about Python Tutor](/a/57532523/4518341), which you might like.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code as mentioned in the comments. Here is a corrected, functional version that simplifies some of your logic and achieves the behavior you seem to be going for.

```
from random import randint

total_points = 0

def generate_guess():
    return randint(1,10)

def check_guess(player_guess, robot_guess):
    global total_points
    correct = False

    if player_guess == robot_guess:
        total_points += 5
        correct = True

    return correct


def retry():
    play_again = int(input("Do you want to play again? 1 for yes, 2 for no: "))

    if play_again == 1:
        main()
    elif play_again == 2:
        print(f"Game over! You ended with {total_points} points!")
    else:
        print("error")


def main():
    print("Let's play the number Guessing Game! ")

    player_guess = int(input("Make a guess: "))
    robot_guess = generate_guess()

    result = check_guess(player_guess, robot_guess)

    if result:
        print(f"You guessed right! You have {total_points} points!")
    else:
        print("You lost this round!")

    retry()

main()
```

The main issues were syntactic.

- Not using parenthesis when calling functions
- Not storing function results
- Issues with passing arguments to functions and returning values

Comment: It'd be nice to fix basic formatting (`retry ()`, f-strings, `global` position, `+=` ignorance, `return(...)`) and naming (`CamelCase` and js-like function names) issues in this code - it is a good way to show beginners existing common conventions and recommend following them.

Comment: @SUTerliakov and Arthur I've updated the answer to reflect more common python conventions for variable names, function names, syntax, and usage of programming constructs